# Code coverage with Intellij, JUnit 5 and Java 11 not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage, junit5

I am trying to run code with coverage in Intellij using JUnit 5. The thing is that I can run all the tests if I don't run with coverage, and they all work perfectly, but when I want coverage, it gives me an error :

```
 Nest member class_info_index 35 has bad constant type in class file XXXX
```

It seems to only happen when I have nested class test like this and coverage runs on JUnit tests with no nested classes :

```
  @Nested
  class WhenDoingSomething {
     @Test
     void aTest(){
        // ...
     }
  }
```

I am using Maven, with JUnit 5 and Java 11

I have tried to add a dependency to JUnit vintage 5.2.0, which didn't give much results.

I also have a dependency to Jacoco in Maven and it can produce an HTML report, but I want the results to appear in my IDE.

Did anyone already had this problem and found the solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: What IDE version do you use? It should be fixed in 2018.3.3.

Comment: Well I updated my version of IDE and it seemed to work ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to update my IDE to the new version :)